# C# python http post to C# httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, python-2.7, websocket, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

i try to figure it out the black box of the server side that code by python for sending http post. In C# i trying to use httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse to send and receive message back from the server side.

**Below is the python code:**

```
  **# Request login to server**

import httplib, urllib, requests
import sys, time
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import select, socket

     s = requests.Session()
    url = 'http://192.168.1.1/request_login' 
        data = 'user.login(test,test)'   #login account and password set here
        r = s.post(url, data=data)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print "Failed loging in (%d)" % (r.status_code)
            sys.exit(-1)



**# send key file to server**

    url = 'http://192.168.1.1/request_sendfile'
    files = {'file': (data_xml, open(data_xml, 'rb'), 'application/x-binary', {'Expires': '0'})}   # **Don't understand this format**
    r = s.post(url, files=files, timeout=30.0)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print "Failed sending data file (%d, %s)" % (r.status_code, r.reason)
        url = 'http://192.168.1.1/request_sendfile' 
        data = 'reader.view_log(4)'
        r = s.post(url, data=data)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print "Failed loging in (%d)" % (r.status_code)
            sys.exit(-3)
        print "Logs: "
        print r.content
        sys.exit(-4)
```

Above is the code for login and sending file to server in one session, i try to use C# do the same way.
I set two http request at the same time, however for the login is success while try to get second http request i get an **error of "400" doesn't understand context of verb**.

**Below is the C# code:**

```
private void httpost()
{
    try
        {
            string Url = "http://192.168.1.1/request_login";
            string Urls = "http://192.168.1.1/request_sendfile";
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
             HttpWebRequest requests = HttpWebRequest.Create(Urls) as HttpWebRequest;
            string result = null;
            request.Method = "POST";    
            request.KeepAlive = true; 
            request.ContentType = "login";  

            string param = "user.login(test,test)";
            byte[] bs = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param);

            using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

               if(resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Login Response Status:" + resp.StatusCode + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Login Response Failed: " + resp.StatusCode + "\n");
                }

                request.KeepAlive = true;
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            using (Stream importFile = requests.GetRequestStream())
            {
                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"data.xml");
                byte[] bytes = ReadWholeArray(fs);   // turn xml file to byte function
                requests.ContentType = "application/x-binary";
                requests.Method = "POST";
                importFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            using (WebResponse responses = requests.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader srs = new StreamReader(responses.GetResponseStream());
                result = srs.ReadToEnd();
                srs.Close();
            }                     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Exception Throw:" + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I try the python code it request login and send file at the same time.
And below is the code that i don't understand.

```
files = {'file': (data_xml, open(data_xml, 'rb'), 'application/x-binary', {'Expires': '0'})}
```